# Which HSV range should I use to get rid of the light green color in this picture?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to pre-process this image for OCR. I want it to be able to read all the text from it, as you can see, the text has different colors. I'm using HSV ranges to detect the colors I want and I just turn everything into white so it's easier for the OCR software to translate the image into text. With my current settings it's reading all the text correctly except the one that it's surrounded by the light green background, I believe the issue is my HSV values, how could I adjust it so it reads all the text?

This is my preprocessing code:

```py
def pre_process_img(img):
    """
    Prepares image for OCR

    :param img: PIL.Image
        Image object

    :return: output_img
    """
    open_cv_image = np.array(img)

    # Convert image to HSV in order to be able to extract what we care about using masks
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(open_cv_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    # Init mask
    mask = 0
    for color_name, data in ocr.COLORS.items():
        if color_name not in ['white', 'dark_red', 'yellow']:
            continue

        lower = np.array(data['lower'])
        upper = np.array(data['upper'])

        # Join masks
        mask += cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

    # Set my output img to zero everywhere except my mask
    # output_img = open_cv_image.copy()
    img_hsv[np.where(mask == 0)] = 0

    # Change image to white where we found the color we want
    img_hsv[mask > 0] = (255, 255, 255)

    # cv2.imshow("out", img_hsv)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    return img_hsv
```

My HSV ranges

```py
COLORS = {
    'dark_red': {
        'lower': [0, 180, 100],
        'upper': [5, 240, 200]
    },
    'red': {
        'lower': [0, 150, 100],
        'upper': [10, 255, 255]
    },
    'white': {
        'lower': [0, 0, 168],
        'upper': [172, 111, 255]
    },
    'blue': {
        'lower': [100, 150, 0],
        'upper': [140, 255, 255]
    },
    'grey': {
        'lower': [36, 50, 70],
        'upper': [89, 255, 255]
    },
    'purple': {
        'lower': [129, 50, 70],
        'upper': [158, 255, 255]
    },
    'green': {
        'lower': [36, 50, 70],
        'upper': [89, 255, 255]
    },
    'yellow': {
        'lower': [25, 50, 70],
        'upper': [60, 255, 255]
    },
    'orange': {
        'lower': [5, 50, 50],
        'upper': [15, 180, 230]
    }
}
```

I know it looks like I don't need all the colors but there are specific examples that use all the colors.

This is the image

[image]

My image to text function in case it's needed

```
def image_to_text(img):
    """
    :param img: PIL.Image
        Image object
    :return: text: str
        Generated text
    """
    # Tesseract path
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

    img = pre_process_img(img)

    
    config = '--oem 3 --psm %d' % 6

    text = image_to_string(img, config=config, lang='eng')
    # Dirty text
    # print(text)
    return text
```

My current output is

```
You have decided to bug § DaddyEredin's house tonight.
10 Pagond has left the game.
9 viagra has left the game.

 

Amember of the mafia visited 8 Blesser last night.
Amember of the mafia visited 14 jesus last night.
Amember of the mafia visited 7 Someone Especial last night.
```

My desired output is

```
You have decided to bug § DaddyEredin's house tonight.
10 Pagond has left the game.
9 viagra has left the game.

 
You were attacked but someone nursed you back to health
Amember of the mafia visited 8 Blesser last night.
Amember of the mafia visited 14 jesus last night.
Amember of the mafia visited 7 Someone Especial last night.
```

Comment: Can you please post an executable code sample? Include the `import` statements and the code that executes your methods. Please also add the version of Tesseract that you are using. (I tried to execute your code, but I am not getting the same results).

Comment: You could extract *image* colors using this [tool](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca)

Comment: @ellhe-blaster Or just load the image using Microsoft paint :)

Comment: to extract hsv is also okay, but if user wants a more detailed description I think it should use mkweb

Answer (score 0):

The green bar and the green text has the same HSV values, so I'm lightening the image with the background. The bar in the resulting image is more saturated, while the text is not.

Also, 5 pixels of the image from both sides is cropped horizontally.

As a general rule, it is best to preprocess colors when there is a conflict.

```py
def pre_process_img(img):
    # crop useless area
    img = img.crop((5, 0, img.size[0]-10, img.size[1]))
    # cut and stretch background strip
    open_cv_bg = np.array(img.crop((0, 0, 1, img.size[1])).resize(img.size)).astype(float)
    open_cv_image = np.array(img).astype(float)
    # blend lighten image with background to saturate the green bar
    diff = blend_modes.lighten_only(open_cv_image, open_cv_bg, 1).astype(np.uint8)

    # Convert image to HSV in order to be able to extract what we care about using masks
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    # Init mask
    mask = 0
    for color_name, data in COLORS.items():
        if color_name not in ['white', 'green', 'yellow']:
            continue

        lower = np.array(data['lower'])
        upper = np.array(data['upper'])

        # Join masks
        mask += cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return mask
```

The image blended with its background to saturate the green background.
[image: saturated image]

```py
COLORS = {
    'white': {
        'lower': [0, 0, 168],
        'upper': [172, 111, 255]
    },
    'green': {
        'lower': [55, 100, 50],
        'upper': [65, 220, 255]
    },
    'yellow': {
        'lower': [25, 100, 70],
        'upper': [50, 255, 255]
    }
}
```

Output

```
a
You have decided to bug § DaddyEredin's house tonight.

10 Pagond has left the game.

9 viagra has left the game.

You were attacked but someone nursed you back to health!
Amember of the mafia visited 8 Blesser last night.

A member of the mafia visited 14 jesus last night.

A member of the mafia visited 7 Someone Especial last night.
```